# How can I get column and value from PDO Procedure call

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new on PHP dev, and I need help.

I have a procedure in MySQL that proc, create a temp table and execute select with parameters received.

So, I'm trying to get that result with PHP and create a HTML Table with column name and values received from this procs. For example:

```
$q= $con->prepare("CALL unicos.NOC_cobranca_conecta_historico_msisdn_V2(:sDDDA, :sNumA, :sDtInit, :sDtEnd)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":sDDDA", $sDDDA, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":sNumA", $sNumA, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sDtInit', $sDtInit, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
    $stmt->bindParam(':sDtEnd', $sDtEnd, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
$q->execute();
```

I try searching here some options but I can't get results. I tried to use this code:

```
while ($arrValues = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $tablestring .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($arrValues as $key=>$value){   
        $column_names[]=$key;
       $tablestring .= "<td>".$value."</td>";
     }
 $tablestring .= "</tr>";
}

$headstring .= "<tr>";
foreach ($column_names as $name)
{   $headstring .= "<td>".$name."</td>";
    }
 $headstring .= "</tr>";

echo "<table>".$headstring.$tablestring."</table>";
```

I'm trying to get Column Name and Value for each line and mount a table with this result. How can I get this? I tried to change 'fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)' to other options and saw some example in the documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) but I don't understand how can I get this into table HTML.

Thanks.